# google app account is not receiving forwarded emails from other non-google app accounts

Tags: exchange, google-workspace

I have two domains

1. abc.co.uk
2. xyz.co.uk

abc.co.uk is registered with google app and mx records are updated according to google app guideline. email address info@abc.co.uk on google app is working fine and receivng direct emails.

my other domain whose mx recording is pointing to its hosted server. and an email address info@xyz.co.uk on that server is created with the forwarding set to two other emails. one is aaaa@gmail.com and other info@abc.co.uk (email set on google app).

I am receiving forwarded emails on aaaa@gmail.com but not receiving on info@abc.co.uk (email set on google app) and I can also see email in my inbox (info@xyz.co.uk) which shows that this inbox is recieving emails and forwording fine.

why google app account is not recieving forwarded emails. is there any other setting i have do?

Anyone faced this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

there are few ways you can check if every thing is configured correctly for mx records use following websites to check.

[mxtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com)
or
[dns squish](http://dns.squish.net/)

if everything is working alright and you need to disable your email services for that particular domain. otherwise your hosted email services might take preference and you emails will not delivered your external server.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a [dns check](http://www.unlocktheinbox.com/dnslookup/mx/abc.co.uk/) on unlock the inbox.

Just change the url to have your real domain name in it. And check out your  PTR and CNAME records. There are tabs for those.